# Is my Xpath Correct for using with Hpple

Tags: ios, xpath, hpple

Is this the correct Xpath //p[id='Q'] for "Who Framed the Law"
Even with this in Hpple gives me a value of null

```
<html>
    <p id="Q">Who Framed the Law?</p>
    <p id="A1">Brian</p>
    <p id="A2">Ted</p>
    <p id="A3">Ki</p>
    <p id="A4">Shane Pizza</p>
</html>

    NSString *XpathQ =@"//p[id='Q']";
    NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [StuffParser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQ];
    NSString *QS=@"";
    for (TFHppleElement *element in tutorialsNodes) {
        QS=[element content];
        NSLog(@"%@",[element content]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "id" is attribute you should use it with @, i.e. `//p[@id='Q']`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an expression like `//p[@id='Q']` .See [xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)